# Regular expression, sort list of URLs alphabetically?

Tags: regex

I used this Regular expression to sort words alphabetically:

```
^.*$
```

Replace with:

```
\&
```

When I tried to sort list of URLs alphabetically, it didn't work.
I use PowerGrep.

I have this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=Florida
https://www.google.com/search?q=Delaware
https://www.google.com/search?q=Hawaii
https://www.google.com/search?q=Alabama
https://www.google.com/search?q=California
```

I want this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=Alabama
https://www.google.com/search?q=California
https://www.google.com/search?q=Delaware
https://www.google.com/search?q=Florida
https://www.google.com/search?q=Hawaii
```

Comment: I'm confused, `^.*$` would just patch everything, it doesn't do any shorting.

Comment: Can you post a larger block of code? Nothing huge, but enough to show context. Also show some sample input and expected output.

Comment: I edited my question. I am still learning regex.

Comment: Regex is for pattern matching not sorting. I'm very confused.

Comment: it can be used for sorting, I find quoted regex here: 
https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/sorting-text-line-field-regexp-emacs

Comment: @Robert in the mentionned article, the regex selects the part of the field value to be used to sort the records. The regex "^.*$" means that all the field value is used to sort the records.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the provided link I think:

- you need a regex to match the whole line (because you want to sort complete lines), "^.*$" should serve that purpose
- you need a regex to match a substring which can meaningfully be used for sorting
- that because the sorting might stop at special character, this could explain why your lines did not get sorted, they are identical until very late in the line and contain many special characters.

So I propose to use

```
[^=]*$
```

instead of

```
\&
```

"[^=]" means "anything but "=".
"*"    means "zero or more times".
"$"    means "must be at end of line".

Sorry, I cannot test this proposal, for lack of emacs.
You might have to adapt quoting of special characters, i.e. trying "\" in different locations.
If this does not help, try to attract an emacs gurus attention, by adding a tag "emacs".